# Set the SYSGEN_NETUTILS variable in your OS design

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-embedded-compact

I need to go through this manual:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197917.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

And I do not understand point 2. It says: "Set the SYSGEN_NETUTILS variable in your OS design to include ipconfig.exe"
Can someone, please, explain what it means and how to do it?

My situation is that I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I want to use it to debug my C++ program on Windows Embedded Compact 2013. Deploying works well for me, but when the exe should be launched I receive error: "A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network." I hope that your answer will help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 in the linked description only applies to OEMs who use Microsoft Platform Builder to create their own, customized OS images.

What it means is that setting the `SYSGEN_NETUTILS` variable includes the `ipconfig` tool in the image, which can then be used to obtain the IP address of the CE device (this is needed in step 4).

If the ipconfig tool is already included in the image (open a command prompt on the device and execute `ipconfig` to check), or if you have other means of determining the device IP address, you can ignore step 2 entirely.

The socket error you are getting indicates an unrelated network configuration issue. To fix it, you will need to modify the network settings on either the CE device or on your host PC to bring the two onto the same network, allowing the PC to connect to the device.